# SonataAdminBundle resource not found

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

after fighting to try to reinvent the wheel and create an admin interface for FOSUB Ive decided to install SonataAdminBundle.

I followed the instructions [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/installation.html) with success.  When I try to update assets as suggested I get the following error from the console:

`Fatal error: Class 'Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle' not found in C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\etrack3\app\AppKernel.php on line 25`

**AppKernal.php extract**

```
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
ln 25>  new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
```

I have added the line into AppKernal.php as instructed which registers the bundle.  Ive also installed the bundle using composer and it is present in the Vendor/sonata-project folder. (and is not red in appKernal [using PHPstorm to validate paths])

Im wondering if its something to do with the autoloader that Ive not set up? Ive not been able to find anything that might suggest that this is a. right, and b. how to fix it if it is.

any help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok weird.

when I installed the sonataUserBundle it seems to have fixed this issue.

part of that process was to manually install doctrineormadminbundle with composer rather than putting the reference in the .json file.  Im presuming that was what fixed it.